# Axis with log scale, how to include tick for 0?

Tags: d3.js, math

I need to have log scale on y-axis of my graph. Since log scale cannot include 0 value in domain, I am having the lower limit of the domain to be 1. This is causing the ticks on the axis to start at 1. How do I get the ticks to start from 0?

```
var yScale_for_axis = d3.scaleLog().domain([1,d3.max(vals)]).range ([height,0]);    

g.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale_for_axis).tickFormat( d3.format(".1e")))
```

I need a tick for 0 because the data I need to plot includes 0. I am yet to figure how to accomodate plotting the 0 values by bypassing the log sclae somehow. But before that I need the 0 tick represented on the axis.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a regular log scale (`d3.scaleLog()`), use a symlog scale (`d3.scaleSymlog()`), which allows zero in the domain.

Here is a demo with a regular, log scale and zero in the domain (it will fail, nothing will show up):

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const scale = d3.scaleLog()
  .domain([0, 1000])
  .range([20, 480])
const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Now the same code with `d3.scaleSymlog()`:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const scale = d3.scaleSymlog()
  .domain([0, 1000])
  .range([20, 480])
const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo...looks like scaleSymLog() was introduced in d3 v5.8...I am having to use an earlier version....so thats not an option